# Bind an array of strings to a column of a datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I am designing a winform which have a datagridview.
I am assigning a datatable to that datagridview.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("items", typeof(string[]));
dt.Columns.Add("dateSold", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    dt.Rows[i]["items"] = new string[] { "pencil" + i, "sharpner" + i };
    dt.Rows[i]["dateSold"] = "0" + i + "/0" + i + "/0" + i;
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Column items is an array of strings. I want to show this array in one coloum of the grid.
But by simply assigning the datatable as the datasource of the datagridview doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're using is a bit strange. There are overloads that would allow you to add a new row and set a value at the same time.

Also, you can't have a string array be a field for a cell. Instead of using a DataTable you could create a custom class, and bind a list of them to the DataGridView. This way you could have an underlying field which is an array of strings, and then have a public property that formats them as you desire, and then displays that in the DataGridView.

Here's a sample of how to approach this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sales As New BindingList(Of SaleTransaction)

        For i As Integer = 1 To 6
            sales.Add(New SaleTransaction(i))
        Next

        ' None of this is necessary since the DGV will automatically read the public properties.. '

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        Dim itemsColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        itemsColumn.HeaderText = "Items"
        itemsColumn.ValueType = GetType(String)
        itemsColumn.DataPropertyName = "Items"

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(itemsColumn)

        Dim dateColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        dateColumn.HeaderText = "Date Sold"
        dateColumn.ValueType = GetType(String)
        dateColumn.DataPropertyName = "DateSold"

        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dateColumn)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = sales

    End Sub

    Public Class SaleTransaction
        Private _items As List(Of String)

        Public ReadOnly Property Items As String
            Get
                Return String.Join(", ", _items)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Property DateSold As Date

        Public Sub New(ByVal itemNumber As Integer)
            Me._items = New List(Of String) From {"Pencil" & itemNumber, "Sharpner" & itemNumber}
            Me.DateSold = Date.Parse(String.Format("0{0}/0{0}/0{0}", itemNumber))
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```